# Did Clemenza kill the elevator operator

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather

In the baptism/murders sequence at the end of the Godfather, Clemenza is seen firing his shotgun into the elevator car twice, however there were three people in the elevator car- Don Stracci, his underboss, and an elevator operator. Does anyone know if Clemenza shot the operator offscreen?

Answer (score 1):

### We don't know but probably not.

If you look at the screen you can see that the elevator operator is shielded from the shotgun blasts as he is standing to one side by the controls.

[image]

The shots are fired straight ahead and so would be unlikely to spread to the side that much.

Of course, it's possible that Clemenza finished him off and disposed of any possible witness **off-screen** but we have no information on that.

Comment: I don't think they cared about the witness. Because when Moe Greene is killed it was only him and not the massager.